# Fastest sequential access

Tags: c++, vector, linked-list

which data structure should we use for fastest sequential access ?

- vector
- Singly linked list
- Doubly linked list

what do we mean  by non synced data structures? some people call vectors synced but some not.

An array can be accessed in random fashion as well as sequential access but a LL can be accessed only in sequential access so how can one decide that arrays are fast or LL, when accessed sequentially?

Comment: This really seems to me to be an assignment question. Have you made any attempt at it yourself?

Comment: yeah googled but wiki says that linklist provide sequential access but i think using arrays we cab traverse sequentially

Comment: Then it's not a list any more is it

Answer (score 1):

> An array can be accessed in random fashion as well as sequential access but a LL can be accessed only in sequential access so how can one decide that arrays are fast or LL, when accessed sequentially?

Because sequential access, when implemented in terms of random access, will be constant when compared to the alternative of *actually* seeking from beginning to `n`, which is linear in time.

For a container with random access, sequential access of element `n` can look like this:

```
cursor := getStartCursor()
cursor := cursor+n
getElementAt(cursor)
```

For a container with only sequential access, it must look like this:

```
cursor := getStartCursor()
for i = 0 to n:
    cursor := getNextCursor(cursor)
getElementAt(cursor)
```

And a single `add` operation is in a different category of algorithmic complexity than `n` dereferences.

As an analogy, sequential access would be an easter egg hunt where you cannot skip to the fourth egg without having already found the first four clues; by contrast, a map of where each egg is will enable you to go to any egg you like, at any time, *including* in the original order.

Comment: so you are saying vectors are fast for sequential access.

Comment: @Azazle: Absolutely. Fast random access implies fast sequential access.

Comment: but vectors may be synced which make them slower

Answer (score 1):

All three of these items have direct access to the next item in the sequence. That said:

While the complexity of sequential access for vectors, linked lists, and double-linked lists may be identical; there is no doubt that vectors will almost always provide the best real-world performance. When looking at the performance of a method, a lot of factors go into consideration, more than just the O(n) or Θ(n) for an operation.

Vectors in the most recent C++ specifications are guaranteed contiguous memory allocation (means the items are immediately after each other in memory), which means looking up one object from the memory will result in the nearby objects also being loaded into the L2 and L1 caches (spatial locality). This means accessing subsequent items in the same vector will be a lot faster since the CPU does not need to get the contents from memory.

For reverse iteration, both the double-linked list and the vector will give you O(1) access to the next (read: previous) item, but again, the same issue stands. A double-linked list will have to do several operations to get to the next node (but it is a fixed number of operations, hence the O(1) value) including reading the value of the pointer to the next object, and loading that address to access its contents. The vector will always have the upper hand here.

Vectors also give you direct access to any random node. Both double-linked and single-linked lists fail to do so - you'll have to iterate from the start (end is also an option for double-linked lists) to get to a random index.

Basically: 99% of the time, you should be using a vector. Never rely on O(n) or Θ(n) for real-world performance as it hides many important metrics. The downside of a vector is that if the number of elements exceeds the amount of space reserved in advance, the vector must resize (and usually that entails a copy of all data to the new location). Smart reservation of a certain size can mitigate this problem; and generally "solving" this by using a linked list is overzealous pre-optimization that ends up hurting rather than helping.

Comment: In _all_ C++ specifications.

Comment: @light Actually, in the original C++ spec it was possible to comply to the spec without having contiguous memory assigned to the items. The spec said the iterators would have to be contiguous, but did not explicitly mention the backing memory. In practice, most implementations provided contiguous memory allocation, but this discrepancy was fixed in the next revision of the spec.

Comment: Hmm you're right; C++98 didn't guarantee it. Never knew that.

Answer (score -2):

The direction of acces salso matters:
Front to Back: All of them are equal (though depending on the vector implementation it may be a tad faster - assignment versus increment)

If you may need to reverse in between: Double-Linked List and Vector (thanks to Mahmoud for pointing that out!)

Comment: How is accessing a linked list in order faster than accessing a vector? A vector guarantees contiguous memory allocation, it's almost guaranteed to be entirely in the cache, does not need separate memory loads for each object, etc., etc., etc. The O() value for sequential lookup may be the same, but that is not the same as the speed! A vector also has the same O() for reverse iteration as a double-linked list, so it makes no sense to recommend that over a vector for such a purpose.

Comment: @Mahmoud: This may be the answer: I augmented my answer (increment of pointer-to-actual vs an assignment. As you pointed out, the elements of a list may be scattered in memory, thus it may lay to more page swaps.

Comment: "May". You also definitely have a ton more dereferences.